# Accessing incoming and outgoing e-mail content

Tags: php, mysql, email, ubuntu

I was wondering how can I access my mail server content (incoming and outgoing)

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
With courier and Postfix installed. (mail server is functioning perfectly)

But I want to create a ticket system for CRM in our web-software (for browser). My idea was to save every one of them in a table (MySQL) but nobody around me has any information on how to do that?

I was wondering if I can forward every mail to script that inserts information to table?

Or maybe i am approaching this wrong, is there another safer way of doing this?

Comment: Sg like this https://www.thecodingmachine.com/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail/ ?

Comment: Or just use pop3/imap to access the mailbox